# Share a range of Cells from a Google Sheet for a user to edit

Tags: google-sheets

Can someone tell me if it is possible to share a selection of columns from Google Sheets and send a link to someone which only gives them access to a certain cell range for them to update which then updates the master document of where the columns are from?

In short, I have one 'Master' document and I only want to share access to 3 of the 28 columns, where someone can edit them and it updates the Master sheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible with Sheets.

You could share the whole document with a specific person or persons, allowing them EDIT authority, and then protect all the parts of the sheet that you don't want them to be able to change.

Another option might be to share a new sheet, that only contains the specific columns you want them to change, and which pulls its data from the master.  If they make their changes in a "data entry" column, adjacent to the primary column, the master sheet could pull that data, when those cells are not blank, to get its updates.

If this sounds useful, and you wanted to provide a sample master, I could maybe demonstrate this.